# LibVLC: Is a filter like v360:fisheye from ffmpeg available in LibVLC?

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, libvlc, fisheye, libvlcsharp

I'm having problem playing fisheye(180) videos panoramically on the fly
using LibVlcSharp in a WinForms appliction.

More specifically: what I want to do is filtering video with libvlcsharp in a WinForms application(c#) with the same effect like

```
-vf v360=fisheye:e:ih_fov=180:iv_fov=180:pitch=90
```

from ffmpeg.

FYI: this will not make the video tagged with equirectanglar projection, the v360=fisheye filter dewarps the video and the video stays rectanglar.

The input video is like this:

[image]

And the the expected output should be like:

[image: output video]

This can be achieved by:

```
./ffmpeg -i input.mov  -vf v360=fisheye:e:ih_fov=180:iv_fov=180:pitch=90,crop=in_w:in_h/2:in_w:in_h/2 output.mov
```

but I need to do this with LibVLC and on the fly.

Can I achieve this with LibVLC's video filter?

Or I need to develop my own filter and make a wrapper for c#?

Comment: is your video tagged as equirectangular properly? Is the VLC desktop 3.0 app able to display it correctly?

Comment: No, video can't be tagged as equirectangular, and VLC is not suitable for my situation.

Comment: I need to play this video in my WinForms application.

Comment: if the video is not tagged properly, VLC won't interpret it as a 360 video. LibVLC can be used from C# WinForms apps through libvlcsharp FYI

Comment: @mfkl Thank you for commenting. I think there is a misunderstanding. What I'm trying to do contains two steps: Step1: dewarp the fisheye video to panoramic style, which is the point of current question; Step 2: play the video with equirectangle projection, which I have figured out with a injection tool provided by Google (the name is something like spatical, as I can recall). Unfortunately, I can't skip step1..

Comment: there is no switch for that. Either the video is properly tagged and it is displayed panomaric style with viewpoint navigation enabled, or it is not and it will show as received with no viewpoint navigation

Comment: I don't know of a tool that can inject this tag from memory buffers, only with a file as input

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @mfkl Yes, only file injecting is possible AFAIK. Thank you anyway.